# Specify a specific mapping for objects in JSON array in RESTkit?

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm receiving this JSON from `django-rest-framework` when I request a list of UserProfile objects:

```
[
    {
        "gender": 1, 
        "show_gender": true, 
        "show_real_name": true
    }, 
    {
        "gender": 2, 
        "show_gender": true, 
        "show_real_name": true
    }
]
```

But I'm at loss how to configure my mappings with Restkit. Restkit seems to expect a [dictionary instead of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403286/restkit-json-mapping-doesnt-work), since it seems to use the dictionary's keys as "KeyPath" to identify the necessary mappings. Is there a way to specify a mapping for the received objects manually?

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

```
// define a mapping
RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ERUser class]];
[userMapping mapAttributes:
 @"gender",
 @"show_gender",
 @"show_real_name",
 nil];

// add the mapping anonymously
[objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:userMapping];

// tell the mapping provider which mapping to use
RKObjectMapping* articleMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[ERUser class]];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/users" objectMapping:articleMapping delegate:self];
```